# Rotate a text by 90deg inside a div and position it at the right end

Tags: css

I am trying to make an info box with an info text (which is a simple div). At the right end of this info box there should be a text named "more info" (a nested div), which should indicate that you can click on the info box. To save space I would like to rotate the text 90 degrees, and it should only take so much space as the height of the text "more info". But I couldn't get it working. Either my text is breaking into two lines, or if I use `white-space: nowrap;` the text is not aligned vertically centered.

Does anyone have a hint for another css property I can try?

I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/girlscout/9e5u3j5w/3/

I colored the two divs with separate colors just for this example in order to see what the divs are doing.

Thank you Brett for hint with the the code snippet (it is my first post, and I didn't know that this is possible). Here is the code:

```css
.first-div {
  border:1px solid blue; width:300px; height:100px; margin:20px auto;
  display:flex;
  /*justify-content:flex-end;  */
}
.second-div {
  background-color:green;
  /*align-items:center;*/
}

.mytext{
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
  </p>
     <div class="second-div"><p class="mytext">more info</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create the code snippet using the [tools on Stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+code+snippet&oq=stackoverflow+code+snippet&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.4659j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I think you cannot do what you want to do because the rotation is performed **after** the text display is computed. Therefore, it will never fit the new orientation. 
CSS is only decoration after the HTML flow is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one key will be the [`transform-origin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

We'll also `position: absolute` the `.mytext` element and fix the width, height and some other properties. However, it still remains flexible enough to work with a variety of content.

Like this:

```css
.first-div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
}

.second-div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: 80px;
}

.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
}

.first-div.larger {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
  </p>
  <div class="second-div">
    <p class="mytext">more info</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first-div">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
  </p>
  <div class="second-div">
    <p class="mytext">info</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first-div larger">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
  </p>
  <div class="second-div">
    <p class="mytext">even more info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Brett, this is a great solution and almost the same as from Jim-miraidev. I wouldn't have come to this solutions myself in years, so thank you for the hint with `transformation-origin`!

Comment: I updated the solution to make it a bit more flexible based on the content of the rotated element.

Answer (score 2):

so you can make it work by setting the width on the .second-div and changing the padding and transform-origin on .mytext, but its going to be different for every tab you create.

```
.second-div {
   background-color: green;
   width: 120px;
   position: relative;
}
.mytext {
   position: absolute;
   white-space: nowrap;
   top: 0;
   padding: 8px;
   color: #FFF;
   transform-origin: 50% 100%;
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jim-miraidev, it worked! This was really helpful, and almost the same solution as from Brett. I only added a `left:-8px` to `.mytext` so that the "more info" text is centered horizontally too. I like both solutions, yours and the one from Brett, and both worked. Hope you don't mind that I accepted the one from Brett because there is no need to position relative or absolute. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem Bettina, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're look for. You need to add positioning to the `first-div` of `relative` and `second-div` of `absolute`. See below code.

See it here: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/jGKmGr)

```css
.first-div {
      border: 1px solid blue; 
      width: 400px; 
      height: 100px; 
      margin: 20px auto;
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      padding-right: 40px;
    }
    .second-div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    .mytext{
      transform:rotate(-90deg);
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 0.7em;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
      </p>
      <div class="second-div">
        <p class="mytext">more info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a possible solution, although it means somewhat duplicating your markup in a way. You will need two elements: the text that serves as an invisible filler, and the text that is actually displayed:

```
<div class="second-div">
  <!-- Used to precaluclate/reserve space, not displayed -->
  <div class="mytext-spacer">more info</div>

  <!-- The actual text that is displayed and rotated -90deg -->
  <div class="mytext">more info</div>
</div>
```

The solution leverages on the fact that you can use a spacer element that "pre-occupies" the space that the rotated text needs. This will be the `.mytext-spacer` element. We simply force it to display text in a vertical manner so that it will take up the same space as rotated text:

```
.mytext-spacer {
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The spacer is then hidden away using `visibility: hidden`. Using `display: none` will not work because it will be taken out of the document flow and will not be able to "reserve" the pre-calculated space required to fit the rotated text.

Next, you simply rotate your actual `.mytext`, it will fit nicely. I have used the position + translate trick to visually center the text. We cannot leverage of flexbox here because it will then interfere with the layout involving the hidden spacer text.

```
.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.first-div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content:flex-end;  */
}

.second-div {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.mytext-spacer {
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
  </p>
  <div class="second-div">
    <div class="mytext-spacer">more info</div>
    <div class="mytext">more info</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first-div">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa sociis nato.
  </p>
  <div class="second-div">
    <div class="mytext-spacer">this is a long long text</div>
    <div class="mytext">this is a long long text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```